# virsh dominfo and xml mem definition different from memory in running vm

Tags: virtualization, rhel6

Hi I just started using kvm on rhel6 and after creating a vm I tried to increase the memory but the changes I amde in the xml file do not propogate to vm, even after bouncing vm and restarting libvert?

```
[root@kvm01 qemu]# virsh dominfo dev-kvm01
Id:             2
Name:           dev-kvm01
UUID:           9b2bf581-2807-3116-b176-60e9c0559943
OS Type:        hvm
State:          running
CPU(s):         2
CPU time:       1975.3s
Max memory:     7864320 kB
Used memory:    7864320 kB
Persistent:     yes
Autostart:      disable
Security model: selinux
Security DOI:   0
Security label: system_u:system_r:svirt_t:s0:c47,c760 (enforcing)

[iknowmed@dev-kvm01 ~]$ free

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3632284    3614508      17776          0       3980    3491676
-/+ buffers/cache:     118852    3513432
Swap:      5668856          0    5668856
[iknowmed@dev-kvm01 ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the 3GB [barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier). Are you running a **32-bit** kernel in the guest VM (dev-kvm01)?

You either need one with [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) or a 64-bit kernel in the VM to use more than 3.6GB of memory available.

Do a `uname -a` to see what kind of kernel you're running.

Answer (score 0):

The 32-bit kernel ships with rhel6 already support > 4 GB RAM. It has already PAE support